# Create elements in js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, createelement

I want to create and element with js in my html with createElement but somethings wrong in my code.

```
HTML
 <button class="prueba_boton">soy una prueba</button>
    <div class="prueba"></div>
JS
    let buttonPrueba = document.getElementsByClassName("prueba_boton");
    buttonPrueba[0].addEventListener("click", funcionPrueba);
    console.log("hola", funcionPrueba);
    function funcionPrueba() {
      var printTextIdDrink = document.createElement("h2");
      printTextIdDrink.setAttribute("class", "TextIdDrink");
      printTextIdDrink.innerHTML = "<span>Bebida:olaaa </span>";
      console.log("me estoy ejecutando");
      document.getElementsByClassName("prueba").append(printTextIdDrink);
    }
```

and here I have the console error
me estoy ejecutando main.js:28:11(console.log(I`m executing)

uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).append is not a function
funcionPrueba http://127.0.0.1:5500/main.js:29
EventListener.handleEvent* http://127.0.0.1:5500/main.js:22

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns elements collection, not single element.

Comment: You can't append to a HTMLCollection.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("prueba")[0]

Comment: You can also use ```document.querySelector('.prueba')```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use getElementsByClassName it returns a collection, so, you can select the element before append:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("prueba")[0].append(printTextIdDrink);
```

Or use an id prop that returns only one element:

```
<div id="prueba"></div>
...
document.getElementById("prueba").append(printTextIdDrink);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```js
let buttonPrueba = document.querySelector(".prueba_boton");
buttonPrueba.addEventListener("click", funcionPrueba);
//console.log("hola", funcionPrueba);
function funcionPrueba() {
  var printTextIdDrink = document.createElement("h2");
  printTextIdDrink.setAttribute("class", "TextIdDrink");
  printTextIdDrink.innerHTML = "<span>Bebida:olaaa </span>";
  console.log("me estoy ejecutando");
  document.querySelector(".prueba").append(printTextIdDrink);
}
```

```html
<button class="prueba_boton">soy una prueba</button>
<div class="prueba"></div>
```